# MSAL Attentication (Microsoft Authentication Library) Failed with Intune Company Portal App

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

I have Created MSAL Attentication(Microsoft Authentication Library) With Xamarin Forms Using TentID and Client ID.Attentication work fine When There is no SMS Two Factor Authentication and when there is SMS Two Factor Authentication There is option Appeare to Enrollment when selecting Enrollment It ask to download Intune Company Portal app . I have installed Intune Company Portal App and Login Intune Company portal and Registered Device But Stuck App in Enrollment Its Appearing This Screenshort.
Again and again .How Now i Can Configure Enroll the Device Login. Is there Any Configuration to fix this type of issue.[image]

Comment: Hi @Zubairz, please go to [Ms document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/user-help/enroll-device-android-company-portal) helps you in configuring Intune and fixing your issue.Please let us know if you still face any issue.

Comment: @Hari Krisgna-MSFT Identity I have Still issue Still not Resolved.

Comment: Hello, I am facing a similar issue in spite of using a managed device. Please let me know if you were able to resolve this.

Comment: No..this error is still pending if you will resolve please reply your answer

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this sample which details all the steps for getting this to work.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2/tree/master/2-With-broker

As far as I know, if a broker (Company Portal) is not installed, then MSAL redirects you so that you can install it. After you install the Company Portal, you need to login / register to it etc. And when you try to login through your app it should now work.

Comment: I have Configure  the Attentication with Broker you can check with https://gist.github.com/TrueTech-Source/c0970d9d60cfbbc41ef9e3b3e245f52d

Comment: I have installed the Company portal intune app and done login device registration etc.I am using Broker but when the user login with Microsoft  the login screen Appear again and again its only come issue with SMS Two Factor Authentication.

Comment: ```public const string BrokerRedirectUriOnAndroid "msauth://UserDetailsClient.Droid/{Your package signature}"```

In the above line code what mean by Your Package signature.